# Qt resourced files

Tags: c++, qt

I have a resource file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>_initData</file>
        <file>_LOGFILE</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

In my code I easily access the first one but cant access the second.

```
QFile file(":/_initData");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "Cannot open file to fill avtomatTable";
}
```

works just fine

```
QFile file(":/_LOGFILE");
if (!file.open(/*QIODevice::Truncate | */QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "Cannot open LOGFILE";
}
```

never works

I'm using KUbuntu. Both files are situated in this project's dir /home/template/_projects/4_Disr.
I misunderstand what is happening and got ready to believe in Cthulhu.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All data encapsulated in resource is read-only, as far as I know...
rcc compiles all resourses into binary form, usually compress them, so you can't access them in write mode.

This means that files which are in your folder taken at compile time and added to file .rcc which is used as source file for your resources. Files on your disk are just source from which resource file being assembled, your program does not uses them, just rcc.

You should create log file as standalone file, and all will work fine. Do not embed it into resource system.

Comment: Thanks dude!=) I created it standalone and it worked but didn't when resourced. You've cleared up what is going on. Thanks one more time!